# How to set size for a String Array using a final int?

Tags: java, arrays, size

I am trying to set the size of a `String` array to the set number of a `final int`.

```
private final int MAXIMUM_RECORDS = 50;
//variables
private int[] movieIDs = {MAXIMUM_RECORDS};
private double[] moviePrices = {MAXIMUM_RECORDS};
private String[] movieTitles = {MAXIMUM_RECORDS};
```

It is returning an error for the `private String[]` and wants me to convert the `private int` to a `String` as the only suggestion to fix the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: for first and second array you create array with 1 element each. The last statement will not compile because `50` is not a `String` but `Integer` and String array cannot hold Integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are trying to use an [Array initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6), which is trying to create the `String` array with one element, the `int`, which is throwing the error. To do the size you must do:

```
private String[] movieTitles = new String[MAXIMUM_RECORDS];
```

Which will create a `String` array with a size of `MAXIMUM_RECORDS`. And similarly with your other `Array`s:

```
private int[] movieIDs = new int[MAXIMUM_RECORDS];
private double[] moviePrices = new double[MAXIMUM_RECORDS];
```

For further information on initializing and creating `Array`'s, please refer to the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `Array` initialization is incorrect. There are three ways to declare `array` in java. If you want to create an `array` with specific size and define the values later you have to like this :

```java
int[] myIntegerArray = new int[size_in_integer];
```

Or if you want to initialize it with values you can do it like this :

```java
int[] myIntArray = {1, 2, 3};
//OR
int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

Declaration procedure is same for primitive types and classes. For example in case of `String` you can initialize like this :

```java
String[] stringArray = new String[3];
String[] stringArray = {"a", "b", "c"};
String[] stringArray = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
```